# Persistent connection string errors in .NET Core DB2 connector

Tags: db2, db2-luw, connection-string

I am migrating a full framework application to .NET Core. Under the full framework, it used the following connection string with the IBM .NET Connector for DB2:

```
"Server=localhost:50000;Database=testdb;"
```

The code then assigned `UserID` and `Password` properties from credentials vault.

Now, under Core, with the IBM .NET Core connector for DB2 specifically v.2.0.0.100 (long-term support, according to IBM), this connection string throws an exception when a connection string builder is created from it:

```
{System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
   at System.Threading.Monitor.ReliableEnter(Object obj, Boolean& lockTaken)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2ConnPool.ReplaceConnStrPwd(String value, String newvalue, Boolean onlyPwd)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Connection.RemoveConnectionStringPassword(String value, Boolean bMask)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2ConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
```

There is no `InnerException`. I presume that some mandatory parameters of the connection string that I am not aware of have to be populated under Core, whereas under full framework they were optional. A careful read of IBM documents on DB2 connector Core yielded no mentions of connection string changes, unless I missed them. This [blog post](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/hybriddatamanagement/blogs/vishwa-hs1/2020/07/12/db2-net-packages-download-and-configure) mentioned no such breaking changes.

Is anyone aware of mandatory connection string parameters that are missing from my connection string specifically for .NET Core connector?

UPDATE:

If I build the connection string manually, by concatenating the original one above with `UserID=MyUser;Password=MyPWD;`, and open a connection to the database, then `DB2ConnectionStringBuilder` works even with the original one above. I cannot wrap my head around it! This makes zero sense. The whole purpose of a connection string builder is to build connection strings from parameters, in a strongly-typed manner. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure Password has some value?

Comment: Password is irrelevant at that point because the connection string is being assigned to the `DB2ConnectionStringBuilder` object, not to the `DB2Connection` object. It is the stated purpose of `DB2ConnectionStringBuilder` to add things later on, including user ID and password. The exception occurs in the c..tor.

Comment: Well, the error shows: `at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2ConnPool.ReplaceConnStrPwd(`

Comment: And what does this mean?

Comment: See, before asking this question, I tried to add `Uid=fake;Pwd=fake` or `UserID=fake;Password=fake` to the conn. str. as per https://tinyurl.com/y9yw2g5n but it changed nothing. I want someone other than me tell the world that this is a bug.

Comment: Could you post the value returned by DB2ConnectionStringBuilder.ToString()? Hiding user ID and Pasw of course.

Comment: It is impossible for me because the exception is thrown from it's c..tor. Side note: we use `DB2ConnectionStringBuilder` specifically to not have to store user ID and password in the connection string.

Comment: IF you believe it to be a software-defect, then first try with the Db2.NET Core 3.1.0.200 driver, and if the same symptom arises then open a ticket with IBM Db2 support.  Stackoverflow is not a defect channel for IBM proprietary drivers.  Db2 support might ask you to collect traces.

Comment: I have the same issue. For a work around I Constructed the DB2ConnectionStringBuilder with no parameter, then set the ConnectionString Property. I could not get the Constructor with (string) to work. Setting the ConnectionString Property did work, Not a Perfect solution, I am interested in the answers this finds. (IBM.Data.DB.Provider v11.1.4040.4; .NET Frameworkv4.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

If you use & IBM.Data.DB2.Core (3.1) nuget package with a connection like:

```
server=my server;database=myDatabase;user id=myUser;password=MyPassword
```

Then OdbcConnectionStringBuilder will be enough (e.g.):

```
var db2Connection = "server=my server;database=myDatabase;user id=myUser;password=MyPassword";
var connectionBuilder = new OdbcConnectionStringBuilder(connection);
var Db2Connection = new Db2Connection(builder.ToString());
```

or something like this:

```
var password = builder["password"]?.ToString();
```

It works fine for me